# Why code of apache(the library 6.0 removed) can also run on Android M phones without measures?

Tags: android, apache, android-gradle-plugin

A strange thing I found:

I have a project used the apache library(like org.apache.http.client.methods...,which is removed in android M).I compile it in SDK 5.0 and it runs success on my nexus 5(run in Android M).

I confirm there is no code like "useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'" in my project.

I decompile my app,can not find the apache codes in dex file...

My IDE:Android Studio 1.5.1
Gradle Plugin Version:1.5.0
Gradle Version:2.12

It is so strange:the project can not build in sdk 6.0,but can run on phone of Android M with out "'useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'".

My first question in stackoverflow and weak in english,thanks for your reading!

Comment: Is this a programming question ?

Comment: thanks for your reply,I think is not a programming quesiton,just so strange.And i don't know is the "useLibrary 'orh.apache.http.legacy'" necessary

Answer (score 0):

Apache Library was removed in API level 23 so if your  `compileSdkVersion` is 23 then it won't find it but if you  `compileSdkVersion` is 22 or below then it will find it.. doesn't matter if you're running your app on Android marshmallow or Gingerbread!

Comment: thank you.i think the phone with Android marshmallow still have Apache library.

Comment: libraries are included at runtime..if you add support library then it will be added at runtime when building your app. same with the apache or any other library.